# Are there any interesting Hilbert spaces that do not present as function spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I was pondering this question in class earlier:

All separable, infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic.  Thus, in particular, any such space is isometrically isomorphic to $L^2[a,b]$, for example.  The latter is a rather concrete space of (equivalence classes of) functions.  The question is, can you think of an interesting Hilbert space that don't immediately *look* like a function space, but because of this isomorphism, can be thought of as one?

Hope this makes sense. Not an important question, just a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

The space of [Hilbert–Schmidt operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) is a Hilbert space with the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^*B)$.

And I suppose that sequences are considered as a special kind of functions. Then... I don't know of any other source of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: If you really want to not view them as operators, as a Hilbert space HS operators are really just $l^2$.